# How to retrieve date from table cell using PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have `xlsx` tables and I use PhpSpreadsheet to parse them. Some cells are formatted as date. The problem is that PhpSpreadsheet returns the values from date-formatted cells in an unspecified format:

```
// What it looks in excel: 2017.04.08 0:00
$value = $worksheet->getCell('A1')->getValue();  // 42833 - doesn't look like a UNIX time
```

How to get the date from a cell in form of a UNIX time or a `DateTimeInterface` instance?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The value is amount of days passed since 1900. You can use the PhpSpreadsheet built-in functions to convert it to a unix timestamp:

```
$value = $worksheet->getCell('A1')->getValue();
$date = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToTimestamp($value);
```

Or to a PHP `DateTime` object:

```
$value = $worksheet->getCell('A1')->getValue();
$date = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($value);
```

Comment: If I'm iterating the cells via `$row->getCellIterator()`, do you happen to know how to determine whether this cell's value is supposed to be a date (and then correctly calls `excelToTimestamp`)?

Comment: @AndreasWong, it is a subject for a separate question. If you have already asked the question, give me a link.

Comment: For people using `$excelSheet->toArray()`, I underline that you should pass a parameter to specify not to format dates: `$excelSheet->toArray(NULL, TRUE, FALSE)`. Later you can get a `DateTime` according to this answer.

Answer (score 18):

When we are iterating with `$row->getCellIterator()` or we might have other kinds of value, it might be useful to use [getFormattedValue](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/1.3.1/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Cell.php#L162) instead

while using `getValue()`

- Full name: Jane Doe => "Jane Doe"
- DOB: 11/18/2000  => 36848.0

while using `getFormattedValue()`

- Full name: Jane Doe => "Jane Doe"
- DOB: 11/18/2000  => "11/18/2000"

Comment: make sure you set it to false $reader->setReadDataOnly(FALSE); otherwise the getformattedvalue() function won't do any change

Comment: thank you @jeandavyNizigama
Without your comment, answer is of no use.

Answer (score 11):

Since i cant add comment just adding an answer for  future users. you can convert a excel timestamp to unix timestamp by using the following code (from accepted answer)

```
 $value = $worksheet->getCell('A1')->getValue();
 $date = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToTimestamp($value);
```

And you can determine whether the given cell is  Date Time using `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::isDateTime($cell)` function.

Answer (score 3):

I hope my answer will complete for those who are lost with reading date. I also had an issue with a column containing dates.
When I read in Excel all dates were at the format d/m/Y, but using PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet, some lines were read as d/m/Y and others as m/d/Y.
Here is how I do:

First, I check the format with ->getDataType()

my default format is m/d/Y but when ->getDataType() returns 's' it becomes d/m/Y

```
$cellDataType = $objSheetData->getCell("D".$i)->getDataType();
$cellFormat = 'm/d/Y';
if ($cellDataType=='s'){
    $cellFormat = 'd/m/Y';
}
$resultDate=\DateTime::createFromFormat($cellFormat, $sheetData[$i]['D']);
```

it works fine

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me on a Symfony 5 application.

But this did:

```
$birthdate =
  \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', ($sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col,$row)->getFormattedValue()));
```

If you use a different format on your Excel make sure to change it.