# PHPSpreadsheet reads certain dates incorrectly

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

Ok, so i have an excel file "file1.xlsx" formatted like this:

```
   A      B       C
1 xxxx 4/30/2019 xxxxx
2 xxxx 5/31/2019 xxxxx
```

And if I try using PHPSpreadsheet to read the column B like this:

```php
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('file1.xlsx');
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $sheet->getHighestRow(); $i++) {
  echo $sheet->getCell("B$i") . " ";
}
```

I get this result:
`43585 43616`

I have no idea what could be causing this. These numbers do not appear anywhere in the spreadsheet, and after some testing I noticed that it doesn't happen on all dates, just some. Can anyone let me know what could be causing this and/or what I can do to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Dates are saved as timestamps in excel. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304795/how-to-retrieve-date-from-table-cell-using-phpspreadsheet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve date from table cell using PhpSpreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304795/how-to-retrieve-date-from-table-cell-using-phpspreadsheet)